# Sql Query to find higher salary

Tags: database, oracle, exists, any

Assuming that department 5 has more than one employee and we want to find the employees who get the higher salary than anyone in the department 5, which one of the statements is true for any arbitrary employee table?

Q1:

```
SELECT e.empid FROM employee e WHERE not exists(SELECT * FROM employee s WHERE s.department='5' and s.salary>=e.salary)
```

Q2:

```
SELECT e.empid FROM employee e WHERE e.salary>any(SELECT distinct salary FROM employee s WHERE s.department='5')
```

Comment: Really, verbatim homework assignments show no imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Q2 isright one, for first query if all people have same salary than not exit makes a problem for result, but for secod query it could be used for every arbitrary .